# using awk to match and sum a file of multiple lines

Tags: awk

I am trying to combine matching lines in file.txt `$1` and then display the sum of `$2 for those matches.  Thank you :).

**File.txt**

```
ENSMUSG00000000001:001
ENSMUSG00000000001:002
ENSMUSG00000000001:003
ENSMUSG00000000002:003
ENSMUSG00000000002:003
ENSMUSG00000000003:002
```

**Desired output**

```
ENSMUSG00000000001     6
ENSMUSG00000000002     6
ENSMUSG00000000003     2

awk -F':' -v OFS='\t' '{x=$1;$1="";a[x]=a[x]$0}END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]}' file > output.txt
```

Comment: No there are multiple lines that could be different, I edited the original post to reflect this.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -F':' -v OFS='\t' '{sum[$1]+=$2} END{for (key in sum) print key, sum[key]}' file
ENSMUSG00000000001      6
ENSMUSG00000000002      6
ENSMUSG00000000003      2
```

Comment: Thank you  very much :).

Answer (score 1):

```
{x=$1;a[x]=a[x] + $2} END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]}
```

Just a typo I guess: instead of adding $0 add $2. That gives me the expected output. And the $1="" is not necessary. To make sure that there isn't anything funny with $2 you may consider 1.0*$2.

Comment: I will give this a try.  Thank you :).

Comment: There's nothing that could be `funny with $2` that would be solved with  `1.0*$2`.